# Similarity matching between images using multiple features in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distance, matching, similarity, measure

In image retrieval matlab project, I have extracted 14 features from each image, and is shown in following Table.

**`Si.No  Feature name    Size                   Example Values` **

```
  1      Feature_1      1x64    {96.02, 100.29, 69.04, 91.23,……89.42}
  2      Feature_2      1x64    {0.070, 0.0671, 0.0876, …….. 0.065}
  3      Feature_3      1x64    {0.837,  0.949,  0.992, 1.015 .…. 1.306}
  4      Feature_4      1x64    { 5.00,  5.831,  8.6023, 6.403,…..8.602}
  5      Feature_5      1x64    {-18.875,  -10.85,  -5.12,  … 39.2005}
  6      Feature_6      1x1      0.6465494
  7      Feature_7      1x1      0.89150039
  8      Feature_8      1x1      0.888859
  9      Feature_9      1x1      0.990652599
 10      Feature_10     1x1      157.8198719
 11      Feature_11     1x1      0.60112219
 12      Feature_12     1x1      0.060502114
 13      Feature_13     1x1      0.139164909
 14      Feature_14     1x1      5.7084825
```

The above set of feature is for single image. To compute the similarity between two images, I tried following ways.

First,  I applied distance computation on a whole feature set by constructing a feature matrix (size: 14 x n ) for an image.

Second, there are 14 distance values are computed from individual features of two images then the individual distance values are added to obtain final distance value. Here the problem is some features dominate and make other features of no effect. (eg. Feature_1 and Feature_10 are gives large distance values, so addition of other 12 feature’s distance to the them will not give any effect. So I normalized the 14 individual distance values to the range 0 to 1, the problem again is small distance values gets too small after normalization.

But in both methods the retrieval results are not satisfactory. Is there any other methods to compute the similarity between images that accounts all the above features with equal importance?

Regards,

P.Arjun

Comment: What do the features represent? Perhaps it would be beneficial not to normalize depending on what they are. Can't you simply use `mse` to attribute a cost for feature distance?

Comment: As I understand it, this is a very deep question. If anyone knew the answer of "how to compare quantities that have nothing to do with each other", we could compare rabbits and screwdrivers. This would for sure be very useful, but I doubt this is even possible. In addition, this question has nothing to do with programming, so I vote to close it down.

Comment: @Ratbert - lolololol

Comment: The features given above are point to point distance values, angle values and scalar features of shapes.